# how to complete 100% test coverage for scheduled apex class

Tags: unit-test, scheduled-apex

I have created one scheduled class for weekly schedule and also created test class for it....now i done with test code coverage..but it only showing 50% of code coverage...

what i am missing?

**Apex class:**

```
   global class scheduledBiWeekly implements Schedulable {
         public static String CRON_EXP = '0  00 1 3 * ?';

         global static String scheduleIt() {
         scheduledBiWeekly sm = new scheduledBiWeekly();
         return System.schedule('Monthly Reconciliation', CRON_EXP, sm);
}


   global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {
         List<Times_of_Account_Transction__c> objectList = new List<Times_of_Account_Transction__c>();  

   for (Time_of_Account__c toa: [
        select Id, Inactive__c, Biweekly_Accrual__c
        from Time_of_Account__c
        where Inactive__c = 'false' AND Account_Type__c = 'PTO'
    ])
    {
     objectList.add(new Times_of_Account_Transction__c(
            Time_of_Account__c = toa.Id,
            Type__c = 'Credit',
            Hours__c = 3.333333333333333

            ));
    }
    System.debug('objectList::'+objectList);
    if (!objectList.isEmpty()){
        insert objectList;
    }

  }

 }
```

**Test class for above apex class:**

```
    @isTest
        private class scheduledWeeklyTest{
           static testmethod void  testschedule(){
           Test.StartTest();
         scheduledBiWeekly sh1 = new scheduledBiWeekly();      
         String sch = '0  00 1 3 * ?';
           system.schedule('Test', sch, sh1);
         List<Times_of_Account_Transction__c> objectList = new List<Times_of_Account_Transction__c>(); 
        Test.stopTest();
     }
    }
```

Please help...

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to insert Time_of_Account__c record as well as your scheduler queries for the data

```
 Test.StartTest();
     //insert test data

     Time_of_Account__c t=new Time_of_Account__c();
    t.Inactive__c='false';
    t.Account_Type__c='PTO';
    //fill all mandatory fields needed
    insert t;

     //Call the static method directly
     scheduledBiWeekly.scheduleIt();

     scheduledBiWeekly sh1 = new scheduledBiWeekly();      
     String sch = '0  00 1 3 * ?';
       system.schedule('Test', sch, sh1);
     List<Times_of_Account_Transction__c> objectList = new List<Times_of_Account_Transction__c>(); 
    Test.stopTest();
```